# CSS Getting Distorted on clicking on "Update Preview"

Tags: 2011, siteedit, 2011-sp1

In Site Editor mode, CSS are getting distorted on clicking "Update Preview" after making changes to website content in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1.

However, once we click "Finish Editing" and exit Site editor mode, the webpages look fine, with their CSS intact.

Are we missing anything? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked out answers to the following questions:  http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2510/css-not-being-rendered-in-previewdynamic-mode , http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3620/css-not-requested-when-using-experience-manager-device-preview and http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2313/blocked-css-files-for-session-preview-only-in-internet-explorer

Comment: yes..the problem was the path set in the cd_dynamic_conf.xml. Problem solved for now. Thanks @Bart Koopman

Comment: By all means answer your own question and give an elaborate answer, so others can find that answer when searching for a similar issue.

Comment: The "Path" attribute value at this node <Host Domain="url" Port="port" Protocol="http" Path="/"/> under /URLMappings/StaticMappings/Publications in the cd_dynamic_conf.xml was incorrect. Once that was set to the correct one the CSS rendered correctly.

Comment: answer by adding a real answer (below), not a comment. Then you can also accept your answer (after a couple of days).

Comment: Or is this a duplicate?

Answer (score 5):

This is now resolved .
The "Path" attribute value at the node  "Host" node under `/URLMappings/StaticMappings/Publications` in the `cd_dynamic_conf.xml` was incorrect. Once that was set to the correct one the CSS rendered correctly.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing how your correct path differed from the default (forward slash?) and how to know what the path should be (relative to the website root, based on a virtual directory, etc).